# Rails Clash of Column Names

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

In my controller I am retrieving all quotes for a user like so:

```
# get all logged in person's quotes
@quotes = Quote.all(
                  :select => '*',
                  :joins => "LEFT JOIN statuses on statuses.id = quotes.status_id LEFT JOIN organisations on organisations.id = quotes.customer_id",
                  :conditions => ['raised_by = ?', @person.id],
                  :order => 'quotes.created_at ASC'
                )
```

Which I then show in my view:

```
<% @quotes.each do |quote| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= quote.name %></td>
        <td><%= quote.partner_ref %></td>
        <td><%= quote.status_name %></td>
        <td><a href="/quotes/view/<%= quote.id %>">View</a></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

The problem is the `<%= quote.id %>` used in the link is returning the `id` column of the joined `Organisations` table. I had the same problem with the `name` column of the `statuses` table since `Organisations` also has a `name` field but I just changed the name of the column but that's not something I can do to the `Organisations` table since it's used extensively elsewhere.

So, is there someway to access the column names using some kind of alias?

Comment: Have you tried using `AS foo` at the fields you want?

Comment: ah, why didn't I think of that before... thanks

Comment: `quote` in this case isn't really a Quote record, it's a hybrid from a JOIN. So, you could try something like, `:select => '*, id as quote_id` (as @TheChamp suggests) and then `<td><%= link_to 'View', show_quote(quote.quote_id) %></td>`. Something like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly question by me.

Query needed was

```
SELECT organisations.name AS organisation_name, quotes.id, quotes.partner_ref, quotes.order_total, statuses.name AS status_name 
FROM quotes
LEFT JOIN statuses on statuses.id = quotes.status_id
LEFT JOIN organisations on organisations.id = quotes.customer_id
WHERE raised_by = 'xx'
ORDER BY quotes.created_at ASC
```

Whereas before the query was simply

```
SELECT * FROM quotes
LEFT JOIN statuses on statuses.id = quotes.status_id
LEFT JOIN organisations on organisations.id = quotes.customer_id
WHERE raised_by = '940'
ORDER BY quotes.created_at ASC
```

So, the corresponding Rails code is

```
@quotes = Quote.all(
                  :select => 'organisations.name AS organisation_name, quotes.id, quotes.partner_ref, quotes.order_total, statuses.name AS status_name',
                  :joins => "LEFT JOIN statuses on statuses.id = quotes.status_id LEFT JOIN organisations on organisations.id = quotes.customer_id",
                  :conditions => ['raised_by = ?', @person.id],
                  :order => 'quotes.created_at ASC'
                )
```

Comment: I don't have visibility to the whole app, obviously, but you are doing a lot of literal SQL using Rails. Is there a reason for that? Rails does do a lot of work for you with its methods to "wrap" the SQL layer. There are cases, though, where going right to SQL is needed for efficiency or special needs. Just wondering. :)

Comment: hmm, I thought the way I was doing it was the 'Rails way' but if I'm doing something wrong then it's just because I don't know any better :) More than happy to take (hopefully constructive :)) criticism and learn the proper way